# Android soap request posting -sample?

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to send the SOAP xml request to php server from android device, as shown below are required parameter for posting request. Currently i am not getting any method or sample to do achieve.Any suggest some samples.

POST /sample/server.php HTTP/1.0

Host:  x.x.x.x

User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.7.3 (1.114)

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1

SOAPAction: ""

Content-Length: 551

Thanks